# I need to get a value in PHP "preg_match_all" - Basic (I think)

Tags: php, preg-match-all

I am trying to use a License PHP System…
I will like to show the status of their license to the users.
The license Server gives me this:

```
name=Service_Name;nextduedate=2013-02-25;status=Active
```

I need to have separated the data like this:

```
$name = “Service_Name”;
$nextduedate = “2013-02-25”;
$status = “Active”;
```

I have 2 days tring to resolve this problem with preg_match_all but i cant :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is basically a query string if you replace `;` with `&`.  You can try `parse_str()` like this:

```
$string = 'name=Service_Name;nextduedate=2013-02-25;status=Active';
parse_str(str_replace(';', '&', $string));

echo $name; // Service_Name
echo $nextduedate; // 2013-02-25
echo $status; // Active
```

Comment: Didn't think of that. It's another way of doing that. +1

Answer (score 2):

This can rather simply be solved without regex. The use of `explode()` will help you.

```
$str = "name=Service_Name;nextduedate=2013-02-25;status=Active";

$split = explode(";", $str);
$structure = array();

foreach ($split as $element) {
    $element = explode("=", $element);
    $$element[0] = $element[1];
}

var_dump($name);
```

Though I urge you to use an array instead. Far more readable than inventing variables that didn't exist and are not explicitly declared.

Comment: Thanks : ) have a goo day!!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you just want to break the text down into separate lines along the semicolons, add a dollar sign at the front and then add spaces and quotes. I'm not sure you can do that in one step with a regular expression (or at least I don't want to think about what *that* regular expression would look like), but you can do it over multiple steps.

1. Use [preg_split()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) to split the string into an array along the
   semicolons.
2. Loop over the array.
3. Use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) to replace each '=' with ' = "'.
4. Use string concatenation to add a $ to the front and a "; to the end of each string.

That should work, assuming your data doesn't include quotes, equal signs, semicolons, etc. within the data. If it does, you'll have to figure out the parsing rules for that.

Comment: Thanks : ) have a goo day!!